# Why indent breaks source code formatting?

Tags: c, indentation

I am using indent to format C source code under Ubuntu this way

```
 indent -linux -l120 -i4 -nut filename
```

Somehow several files have broken formatting after indenter. The result looks like this

```
unsigned char get(const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned char *byte) 
{




unsigned char size = sizeof(char);




*byte = *buffer;




return size;




}
```

instead of this

```
unsigned char get(const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned char *byte)
{
    unsigned char size = sizeof(char);
    *byte = *buffer;
    return size;
}
```

What is the reason and how to ensure correct indentation?

Comment: How does the original look like? I do get a decent output when I pass your first example through `indent -linux -l120 -i4 -nut`

Comment: Do you use 4-space tabs ? It might be the reason why you have 4 linebreaks between every LOC

Comment: I could say that I got pretty output too. My indent version is: `GNU indent 2.2.11`

Comment: The source is the same however if I copy paste it here http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=abJpFpe0 it starts indenting correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`indent -linux -l120 -i4 -nut` gives me a sensible output when I use your example text. For example:

```
[me@home]$ cat x.c
unsigned char get(const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned char *byte) {
unsigned char size = sizeof(char);
*byte = *buffer;
return size; }

[me@home]$ indent -linux -l120 -i4 -nut x.c
[me@home]$ cat x.c
unsigned char get(const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned char *byte)
{
    unsigned char size = sizeof(char);
    *byte = *buffer;
    return size;
}
```

so this isn't a problem with `indent`.

My suspicion is that you have dodgy EOL characters in your file which are not acknowledge by `indent`. Try running your file through `dos2unix` before `indent`.

Comment: Thanks, indent works correct after `dos2unix -ascii -1252 filename` call.